# Conky text goes black, 18.04, Intel

Tags: conky

[image: Screenshot]

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_class conky-semi
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 128
# Update interval in seconds
update_interval 240


# Draw shades?
draw_shades no

# Text stuff
draw_outline yes # amplifies text if yes
draw_borders no
use_xft yes
xftfont Monotype Verdana:size=12:weight=normal
xftalpha 0.8
uppercase no # set to yes if you want all text to be in uppercase
text_buffer_size 4096
default_outline_color black





# Text alignment, other possible values are commented
#alignment top_left
#alignment top_right
#alignment bottom_left
alignment bottom_right

maximum_width 500

# Gap between borders of screen and text
gap_x 10
gap_y -170

# stuff after ‘TEXT’ will be formatted on screen
TEXT
$color 


${color AF7AC5} Mbl 
${color white}${rss https://mbl.is/feeds/fp 60 item_titles 5}

${color AF7AC5} Visir 
${color 5DADE2}${rss http://visir.is/rss/frettir 60 item_titles 5}

${color AF7AC5} Ruv 
${color F7DC6F}${rss http://ruv.is/rss/frettir 60 item_titles 5}
```

Comment: Try changing to `#default_outline_color black` and then hopefully white text appears.

Comment: What is "own_window_class conky-semi"? I searched `man conky` for "conky-semi" and found nothing.